# Content blurred in chrome after applying transform scaling and animate at the same time

Tags: css, html, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

Whenever there is an animation on the page, only then the transform scaling element get blurred (text and images). This usually happens only in Chrome. [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/khurram_khu/b461j8cs/).

I have investigated into this but unfortunately got nothing.

Blurred Snapshot:

[image: Blurring]

Only work around I see that works for me is that if the animated object's `z-index` is higher than the transformed element. But in my case I cannot always keep the animated object on higher `z-index`.
eg.

```
.animated
{
   animation-name: second;
   animation-duration: 60s;
   z-index: 5;
}

.transformed
{
   -webkit-transform: scale(2.5, 2.5);
   z-index: 2;
}
```

After z-index fix:

[image: z-index fix]